# Is it okay to operate relay boards with less than voltage specified?

Tags: electronics, home-automation, relay

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6ZagKRnRdM) video where the user explains that he is using Raspberry Pi to trigger the relay board, which requires 5v.

But he says it's okay do it with the 3.2V that's from GPIO.

Does doing this harm the relay board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relay board in question has to power inputs, VCC and JD-VCC. The person tells it's okay to put 3.3V on VCC. But you still need 5V on JD-VCC.

This 3.3V is only used to power the opto-couplers.

If 3.3V were not to be enough, the opto-coupler would work, and the rest of the circuit won't do anything. But nothing bad will happen.

It is actually a good thing to power it using 3.3V as powering it using 5V might make the relay trigger even if the GPIO is set to HIGH. Please follow his advice.

Even more info can be found in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/15430/7863)

Comment: such relays from ebay are reliable?

Comment: They probably use cheaper relays, so they probably fail after fewer switching actions. (The contact wear out every time you engage and disengage, because of arcing). I wouldn't want to use them for anything while I'm not in the building, but I'm quite anal about safety.